# Align text in different containers (flexbox)

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2em;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2em;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="title">Comments</h1>
  <p class="subtitle">
    <em> A simple app that allows a user to input comments</em>
  </p>
</header>
<main>
  <!-- Use dashes in css classes -->
  <section class="comment-input">
    <p>Add Your Comment:</p>
    <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" />
    <button>+</button>
  </section>
  <section class="comments">
    <p>This is the first comment</p>
    <p>Here's the second one</p>
    <p>And this is one more</p>
    <p>Here is another one</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

I want the paragraph text in the header (.subtitle) to align with the paragraphs in the '.comments' section. How do I do that in flexbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both the `<header>` and `<main>` are having a flexbox, choose the first element in `header` and the first element in `main` and assign a flex of `20%` to them. Don't forget to assign `100-20%` to the second elements of `main` and `header`

```
.title, .comment-input {
  flex: 20%;
}

.subtitle, .comments {
  flex: 80%;
}
```

Here's the link to [codepen](https://codepen.io/geekyquentin/pen/RwQKryW)

---

**Tips:**
Try to avoid repetition of properties in CSS. I have modified the CSS code that avoids the repetition of assigning properties.

```
.container, header, main {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  align-items: center;
}

.title, .comment-input {
  flex: 20%;
}

.subtitle, .comments {
  flex: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The 20% and 80% are the flex-basis in this case correct? Not the flex-grow

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is just to add a padding on the paragraph or you can wrap your header in a div and give it a different gap. Like the samples below;

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5.5em;

}

main {
    display: flex;
    gap: 2em;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="header">
                <h1 class="title">Comments</h1>
                <p class="subtitle">
                    <em> A simple app that allows a user to input comments</em>
                </p>
          </div>
            </header>
            <main>
                <!-- Use dashes in css classes -->
                <section class="comment-input">
                    <p>Add Your Comment:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" />
                    <button>+</button>
                </section>
                <section class="comments">
                    <p>This is the first comment</p>
                    <p>Here's the second one</p>
                    <p>And this is one more</p>
                    <p>Here is another one</p>
                </section>
            </main>
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 2em;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    gap: 2em;
}

.subtitle {padding-left: 53px;}
```

```html
<header>
                <h1 class="title">Comments</h1>
                <p class="subtitle">
                    <em> A simple app that allows a user to input comments</em>
                </p>
            </header>
            <main>
                <!-- Use dashes in css classes -->
                <section class="comment-input">
                    <p>Add Your Comment:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" />
                    <button>+</button>
                </section>
                <section class="comments">
                    <p>This is the first comment</p>
                    <p>Here's the second one</p>
                    <p>And this is one more</p>
                    <p>Here is another one</p>
                </section>
            </main>
```